# A network has many conflicting edges. How to create a good visualization for it?

Tags: data-visualization, networks, javascript

I'm having a network of [belief system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juNuGdd_Cc0). It has ~100 nodes, 316 regular edges and 78 conflicting edges. (If belief B conflicts with belief A, then node B and node A share a conflicting edge. If belief B is a logical consequence of belief A, then node B and node A share a regular edge.) I think the best way to illustrate this graph is to have:

1. nodes in the same community being closed together,
2. nodes conflicting to each other being far away,
3. conflicting edges that are almost parallel with each others being closed to give an idea of bundle

By "almost parallel" I mean if set S of closing nodes has many conflicting edges with set T of closing nodes, then the edges between them are almost parallel. The emphasized edges in this image illustrates that:

[image]
<sub>I ask a detailed question about this here: [Is there a concept for "almost parallel" edge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/550101/59765)</sub>

Is that a good way to visualize the network? If yes, then how should I set up the physics? I can do the first two points but I'm failed to do the third one. I'm using [vis.js library](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/physics.html#), and it recommends the [Barnes-Hut Algorithm](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut). The above image is generated with this setting:

| Options | Value |
| --- | --- |
| gravitationalConstant | -10000 |
| centralGravity | 4.75 |
| springConstant (regular edges) | 0.205 |
| springLength (regular edges) | 95 |
| springConstant (conflicting edges) | 0.01 |
| springLength (conflicting edges) | 1000 |

Comment: It sounds like you have a single set of beliefs with two relations on it. You could plot these as separate graphs with a shared choice of embedding. But most important thing is **what do you want to show**? What is the relevant story in this data that you're trying to emphasize?

Comment: hmm yes I was thinking about splitting up into two separate graphs. I don't understand what you mean by "shared choice of embedding", can you elaborate? I want to show that there is a network of beliefs like this, and to show the conflicts between the beliefs

Comment: An embedding of a graph is an assignment of points to each vertex in the graph in which those points are members of a space. Simply put, you could place the vertices in the same places in both diagrams.

Comment: If you have a graph representation showing which pairs of beliefs are conflicting, doesn't a plot showing the edge set of this graph being non-empty illustrate that there are conflicting beliefs?

Comment: @Galen can you give an example of a plot showing the edge set being non-empty? I don't quite understand it. It's not about showing the there are conflicting beliefs. It's about visualizing them meaningfully. (Plotting as separate graphs is a good idea, but having them into one graph also reveals the whole picture)

Comment: [This plot is an example](https://i.imgur.com/eJey4Rdm.png).